# Remove all letters from file names on a mac

Tags: macos, rename, bulk

I have about 300 photos which are a string of letters and numbers, Im planning to data merge these into an indesign document and would like to use the numbers only as these IDs are related to customers and their quotes.

I need to remove every letter or space or symbol from the file names leaving only the id number. is this possible?

```
Here's an example of the file names:
148132durrnt-photojosh.jpg, 173722dumellphotojosh.jpg, 173816mxwell.jpg, 176764very.jpg, 176876pyumo.jpg, 178054plnt.jpg, engll170774pijosh.jpg, entley166282pijosh.jpg, hodgkinson169226pijosh.jpg
```

So there's a mixture of some with the number at the start, some at the end, some in the middle, and a couple dont actually have the numbers at all so those should be ignored..

I don't know of a way to do this other than manually, and wanted to try save some time..